# CSS - Blur background at the background size level and not the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: Final][image: Intermediate]I would like to get the background blurred. But I would like the blur not to be apply on the `header` but rather having a blur on each individual repeated `images`

Is it possible ?

https://jsfiddle.net/9zphnLn5/

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    min-height: 135px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.header:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image:url('https://graph.facebook.com/311194819319371/picture?type=small');
   width: 500px;
   height: 200px;
   -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  margin:auto;
}

.header > img {
  max-width:300px;
  max-height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

<img src="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/18920203_10155138319170250_8020114684159382803_n.jpg?oh=744adfdc78b6581fa999f0c498889e05&amp;oe=599D7A74" alt="Cover picture "></div>
```

Comment: Based on the 2 given answers, this can be interpreted in more than 1 way, so could you show a drawing of the expected output and also explain what _repeated images_ mean.

Comment: I added two pictures. The second one is the `intermediate render`. The first one is the `final render` I wish to have. The important thing is I would like to avoid multiplying the img manually.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please comment on it to clarify what is missing or need an adjustment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `background-size` you control the size, and if to be repeated you use `background-repeat`

To make the `blur` not affect the `header` itself the pseudo has to be *on top*, not *beneath* as it is now, using `z-index: -1`, so I removed the `z-index`.

Since the pseudo has a position, other than `static`, so must also any other child element of `header`, or else they will end up *beneath* it, so here I also gave the `img` `position: relative`.

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 40px;
  min-height: 200px;
  
  /* added the image here too, so one see it is not blurred */
  background-image: url('https://graph.facebook.com/311194819319371/picture?type=small');
  
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.header::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  background-image: url('https://graph.facebook.com/311194819319371/picture?type=small');
  background-size: auto 60px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
.header > img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 150px;
}

.header.nr2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.header.nr2::before {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/18920203_10155138319170250_8020114684159382803_n.jpg?oh=744adfdc78b6581fa999f0c498889e05&amp;oe=599D7A74" alt="Cover picture ">
</div>

<div class="header nr2">
  <img src="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/18920203_10155138319170250_8020114684159382803_n.jpg?oh=744adfdc78b6581fa999f0c498889e05&amp;oe=599D7A74" alt="Cover picture ">
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like a mix of the two versions. If you look to the second picture I uploaded. The `blur` is applied on each smaller background images. In your first example, images are repeated but the blur is applied to the container `header`.

Comment: @Leo Updated...added the image to the header as well, just so you see it is not blurred...is this what you want?, if yes, I'll explain what I did

Comment: @Leo Thanks ...updated my answer with an explanation

Answer (score 0):

The effect you want is technically possible, but the code is not going to be pretty. You can add a `position: absolute` div with a negative z-index and as many individually blurred images as you need.

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    min-height: 135px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}
.bg-pics {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
.bg-pics-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
.header > img {
  max-width:300px;
  max-height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<div class="bg-pics-container">
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/311194819319371/picture?type=small" class="bg-pics">
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/311194819319371/picture?type=small" class="bg-pics">
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/311194819319371/picture?type=small" class="bg-pics">
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/311194819319371/picture?type=small" class="bg-pics">
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/311194819319371/picture?type=small" class="bg-pics">
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/311194819319371/picture?type=small" class="bg-pics">
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/311194819319371/picture?type=small" class="bg-pics">
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/311194819319371/picture?type=small" class="bg-pics">
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/311194819319371/picture?type=small" class="bg-pics">
</div>
<img src="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/18920203_10155138319170250_8020114684159382803_n.jpg?oh=744adfdc78b6581fa999f0c498889e05&amp;oe=599D7A74" alt="Cover picture ">
</div>
```